# How to identify renamed files in pre-commit hook

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I need differentiate the renamed files from list of committed files in per-commit hook.

for example,
I have check out a directory which contains the more number of files. I renamed some of the files, deleted some of the files, modified some of the files, Added some of the files & committed the folder.

here, I need to identify only the renamed files.

Thanks...,

Comment: Finally got it... by using 'svnlook changed' command with '--copy-info' option

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it :)